# call PHP image as CSS background-image: url

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code in my html markup :

```
<div class="profile-img">
    <img src="<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>" />
</div>
```

This code generates a profile image or avatar.

I'd like to use it into CSS as a background image.

So this is what I am trying to use :

```
<div class="profile-img">
     <style type="text/css">
        .profile-img img { background-image: url('<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>'); }
     </style>
</div>
```

My CSS then looks like this :

```
.profile-img {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.profile-img img {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 5px !important;
background: #fff !important;
border: none !important;
border-radius:500px;
-moz-border-radius:500px;
-webkit-border-radius:500px;
background-position: center center;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a round image thumbnail - avatar with proportionally cropped image.

But it seems that the code I am trying to use to call the image into CSS doesn't do the trick.

Where am I going wrong here ?

Comment: What URL are you getting back?

Comment: a background image for a `<img>`? That's rather... redundant.

Comment: Styles should go in the `head` and not the `body`. Definitely not in the middle of a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this rule removing `background-image` property that will be parsed via php.

```css
.profile-img {
    background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-img"></div>
```

So your final html addition will be:

```
<div class="profile-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. It sounds like a solution, but a little confusing.  Should I be using the gravatar url as in your answer or is it just an example ?

Comment: Gravatar is just for demo, image will be fetched from your php code (please check last line).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be a background-image and not part of an IMG tag, and you need it to be dynamic, then you'll need something more like this:

```
<div class="profile-img" style="background:url('<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>') no-repeat center center #ffffff"></div>
```

This will place the image as a background within the .profile-img DIV. Then you'd style just your DIV:

```
.profile-img {
     width: 90px;
     height: 90px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px !important;
     border: none !important;
     -moz-border-radius:50%;
     -webkit-border-radius:50%;
     border-radius:50%; }
```

To be honest, I haven't checked your CSS as I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish beyond the circle shape. I changed your border-radius to 50% as that's what'll create a circle.

Comment: Many thanks, I am definitely getting somewhere with this. At least I get the image going through now. Not centered and cropped yet, but it is there. I guess I just need to play around with the css now. I am trying to achieve displaying an image as an avatar, but cropped and centered, just like this here : [link]http://pho.to/8s3oz

Comment: The image is centered in the circle 90px x 90px, but using it's original size. Is there a way to shrink the image like this : [click me](http://pho.to/8s3oz) ?

Comment: On .profile-img, try adding either background-size:cover or background-size:contain

Answer (score -3):

Im not sure, but a while back I used some css to have round corners for an webapp. Perhaps this will help you:

```
.myImg img{
-webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Hope this helps

```
<script>
 var imageSrc = "<?php echo $user_meta['profilepicture'][0]; ?>";
 $('.profile-img').css('background-image',imageSrc);
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly how does adding some javascsript into this, using undefined variables, solve anything?

Comment: @MarcB - How the var will be undefined when the php script echo's the profile pic's url ?

Comment: at the time you didn't have code formatting, so the tags were invisible.b ut still... if dumping the url directly into the css doesn't work, why would it work by dumping it into the JS?

Comment: `$` will be `undefined` as well, unless the OP is improperly enqueueing jQuery. Regardless, jQuery is overkill for this.